# how to run build in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
   public class incometax {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your income in lacs ");
    float tax=0;
    float income= sc.nextFloat();
        if (income < 2.5f) {
            System.out.println("You do not need to pay tax");
        } else if (income > 2.5f && income <= 5.0f) {
            tax = tax + 0.0f * (income - 2.5f);
            System.out.println("You don't need to pay taxes");
        } else if (income > 5f && income <= 7.5f) {
            //tax=tax+0.0f*(income-5f);
            tax = tax + 0.1f * (income - 5f);
        } else if (income >= 7.5f && income <= 10f) {
            //tax=tax+0.0f*(income-2.5f);
            tax = tax + 0.1f * (income - 5f);
            tax = tax + 0.15f * (income - 7.5f);
        } else if (income > 10f && income <= 12.5f) {
            tax = tax + 0.1f * (income - 5f);
            tax = tax + 0.15f * (income - 7.5f);
            tax = tax + 0.2f * (income - 10f);
        } else if (income > 12.5f && income <= 15f) {
            tax = tax + 0.1f * (income - 5f);
            tax = tax + 0.2f * (income - 7.5f);
            tax = tax + 0.2f * (income - 10f);
            tax = tax + 0.25f * (income - 12.5f);
            //tax=tax+0.15f*(income-10f);

        } else if (income > 15f) {
            tax = tax + 0.1f * (income - 5f);
            tax = tax + 0.15f * (income - 7.5f);
            tax = tax + 0.2f * (income - 10f);
            tax = tax + 0.25f * (income - 12.5f);
            tax = tax + 0.3f * (income - 15f);
        }
          System.out.println("Your total tax is :" +tax +"lacs");
      }

    }
```

everything fine in this code but my intellij idea not working properly whenever i rum this or any file there ide start running another file and says build failed
please help me

Comment: Please help us with the exact error that you are facing and try to follow the [proper naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) while coding as I can see the class name is starting with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

you can build Java program using `javac program1.java.`
or you can try this Move your code inside of the src folder. Once it's there, it'll be compiled on-the-fly every time it's saved.

IntelliJ only recognizes files in specific locations as part of the project - namely, anything inside of a blue folder is specifically considered to be source code.

Also - while I can't see all of your source code - be sure that it's proper Java syntax, with a class declared the same as the file and that it has a main method (specifically public static void main(String[] args)). IntelliJ won't run code without a main method (rather, it can't - neither it nor Java would know where to start).